# Optimizing Autolayout performance

Tags: macos, autolayout

I have an application that uses autolayout to position `NSTextFields` to create editable mathematical expressions. The layout part works fine. The problem is, that when more rows are added the layout procedure starts slowing things down and typing starts to lag.

Since I know that only the edited row needs to be recalculated for layout, is there any way to tell autolayout that the subviews of all the other rows (`NSViews`), don't need to be recalculated, only the position of the rows (parent views) below the row beeing edited?

I'm not using `NSTableView` for the rows. I'm laying them out with autolayout.

Comment: Is this iOS or osx? You talk about UITableView but also nsview

Comment: Sorry for the confusion--osx right now. Just added iOS because I'll be doing an iOS version later. I'll remove that tag.

Comment: The UITableView was also a mistake. I'm pretty shure that I wrote NSTableView so maybe autocorrection intervened.

Comment: No worries, just checking :D

Comment: Could you show the code that you're using when you're adding a new row?

Comment: Are you *sure* autolayout performance is the problem? i.e. Have you run your app in the sampler template of instruments and seen autolayout methods as the smoking gun in the samples? I ask because I've had hierarchies of several hundred views laid out with autolayout and it was *more* than fast enough to keep up with a scrubbing window resize at 60FPS.

Comment: Good point! I just assumed it was autolayout since it is a problem of polynomial complexity. I'll check with instruments.

Comment: This resource may help you: http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/21/auto-layout-performance-on-ios. Florian Kugler has done some Autolayout performance research already.